# Energy in ideal gas in isenthalpic process

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

In an irreversible isenthalpic process, where does the energy of ideal gas go?

Since the temperature remains constant and pressure drops accompanied by an increase in entropy,

is there any expression showing that total energy remains constant in the form of pressure drops.
like a T$\delta$S relation which confirms this  statement

Even if the energy drops in some way could you give an experessio to quantify that?

Comment: Are you referring to a throttling process?

Comment: Actually I encountered it in irreversible adiabatic compression of an ideal gas and what changes happen when it is stagnated by an irreversible adiabatic process. But for the purpose of understanding throttling will work equally well.

Comment: But you said the pressure drops. How can that be if it’s an adiabatic compression?

Comment: sorry I wrote it mistakenly, I meant stagnation instad of compression

Comment: Also I know that internal energy remains constant but what does change? exergy?

Comment: If you know the internal energy remains the same then why are you asking “where does the energy of the ideal gas go “? If the process is irreversible then entropy is generated and can be calculated by assuming a reversible process between the initial and final equilibrium states.

Comment: I have updated my answer in response to your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understand the type of isenthalpic process you are referring to (seem my comments on your post).

But it doesn't matter because if it's an ideal gas and there is no change in temperature, then there is no change in internal energy for any process. For an ideal gas, any process,

$$\Delta U=mC_{V}\Delta T$$

> Also I know that internal energy remains constant but what does
> change? exergy?

What changes is that entropy is generated by an irreversible process. If the irreversible process involves an ideal gas, is adiabatic,  and there is no change in enthalpy or temperature between the initial and final equilibrium states, then

$$\Delta U=0$$

$$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (pV)=\Delta (pV)=p_{2}V_{2}-p_{1}V_{1}=0$$

$$p_{2}V_{2}=p_{1}V_{1}$$

An example is a throttling process involving a valve where the gas expands rapidly decreasing in pressure and increasing in volume. The initial and final enthalpies are the same. The rapid expansion makes the process irreversible and generates entropy.

In order to calculate the entropy generated one can assume any convenient reversible process connecting the two equilibrium states and evaluate the integral

$$\Delta S_{1-2}=\int_1^{2}\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}$$

The reversible process need not bear any resemblance to the actual process. That's because entropy is a state function that does not depend on the path connecting the equilibrium states. For a more detailed explanation, see Granpa Chet's entropy recipe here: https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

The obvious choice in this case is a reversible isothermal expansion process. For that process

$$Q=W=(mRT)ln\frac{V_{2}}{V_{1}}=(mRT)ln\frac{p_{1}}{p_{2}}$$

And

$$\Delta S=\frac{Q}{T}=(mR)ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}=(mR)ln\frac{p_1}{p_2}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok I got your point. Though not stated clearly I wanted to know what is the essential difference in the two states, temperature hence enthalpy and internal energy remains same and pressure drops, but entropy rises, so where does this loss in pressure get compensated as overall energy remains the same, Does it go to an entropy related expression?

Comment: @SauravKumar The drop in pressure is compensated by the increase in volume so that $\Delta (pV)$ is unchanged. If the process occurred very slowly, it would be a reversible isothermal process and no entropy would be generated,  only transferred. It is only because the expansion occurs rapidly that entropy is generated.  Entropy goes up the more rapidly the pressure drops and volume increases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are referring to an ideal gas, since you conclude that $\Delta T= 0$ when $\Delta H = 0$. I will continue under the same assumtpion.

When an ideal gas undergoes an irreversible isenthalpic process its energy does not change. Here is an example:

A rigid insulated box is divided into two parts: one part contains an ideal gas at $T_1,P_1$ and the other part is evacuated. We remove the partition and let the gas expand irreversibly to the entire volume of the gas. By first law,
$$\Delta U = Q + W\tag{1}$$
The box is insulated ($Q=0$) and and no work is done since expansion is against vacuum ($W=0$), therefore,
$$\Delta U = 0\tag{2}$$
Since this is an ideal gas Eq 2 says $\Delta T=0$, and also  $\Delta H = 0$.

So here we have an example of an ideal gas undergoing an irreversible isenthalpic process. The final pressure is lower, but the energy of the gas has not changed ($\Delta U = 0$).

For non-deal gas the experiment I described will not be neither isothermal, nor isenthalpic.